# Accurate Smartphone Sensors Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am working on a project "Smartphone Positioning System using Sensors".

I am going to calculate the position of the device using the sensors gyro, accelerometer, magnetometer, proximity etc. So I need to know the best device to select for this so that the sensors data is accurate.

I looked into some: Galaxy Tab 2, S3, S3 mini, Nexus 4. I need to know the device with best accuracy to implement this.

and if possible can you mention the sensors model e.g. in Galaxy Tab we have MPU 3050.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware question.  Unless you can find a web site that's done tests that address your specific query, I'm afraid that you're on your own.

Comment: It just came to my mind that some developers might already have worked on such projects, using the smartphone sensors so just wanted to ask about their experience of the accuracy

Comment: Not sure if there's a stackexchange.com site for these kind of questions, but as I'm sure you know, stackoverflow.com is for programming queries instead.